# Firefox repeatedly asks about installed add-ons at launch

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

Whenever I start Firefox, it asks about installing all the add-on which I have already installed. How to get rid of this problem?

I update my browser regularly. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalled the latest version but still the problem is there. It doesn't happen all the time, though, but like 4 to 6 times out of 10. Is it some kind of bug or do I need to do some setting for this? Or do you guys think any particular add-on is causing this problem?

Comment: try reinstalling the plugin itself in the addons menu

Comment: If you have a lot of add-ons, Firefox will sometimes inquire (especially after an update or problem), whether you want to use them all. They can slow Firefox down, so the question is to ensure you get the best user experience.  My own experience is that once you respond, it doesn't get asked again unless there was a change, like an update, or a problem with Firefox.

Comment: I suppose you checked you make sure you don't have sync turned on?

Comment: @aparente001:- Its was turned off already.